# Checking straight line or not depending on points at Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I want to know the points(Gmarker) on the google map drawn the line or not.
 If line , I want to alert him "your points is drawn line" with
 javascript function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if points are A,B,C,D,E

1. Check "as the crow flies" distance of A to E
2. Find distance between individual points A to B, B to C, C to D and D to E
3. If sum of these 4 distances equals distance from A to E, points are in straight line